# How to Disable the ASP.NET v4.0 Extensionless URL feature on Windows Azure

Tags: asp.net, azure

i've a website on azure with Framework 4.5. I specified a defaultdocument that is also the destinationpage of the login page, in fact when i request the url http://xx.azurewebsites.net it redirects on the login page, all this because i want that the user first authenticate himself.

After login, browser redirects to the right page but the url is showing http://xx.azurewebsites.net again and this causes logout control to not logout the user because when the button is pressed, the page refresh itself and doesn't do the logout.

I found on the web the cause that is Extensionless URL feature of ASP.NET 4.0 and i found how to disable it but it doesn't work. What i found is this code to insert in web.config file of the website:

```
<handlers>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrl-Integrated-4.0"/>
  <remove name=" ExtensionlessUrl-ISAPI-4.0_32bit "/>
  <remove name=" ExtensionlessUrl-ISAPI-4.0_64bit "/>
```

Any ideas???

Comment: Ideas - fix what sounds like a bug in your code for `logout` instead of your current approach of disabling a feature (that likely isn't the culprit in the first place).

Comment: That should work - it didn't for me at first either, but then I tried it via the IIS Manager UI (handler mappings section) and it did the trick, even though it just adds the same entries. Maybe something to do with the spaces or the order?

Comment: Ah, I found the problem - it should be ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0 - you're missing 'Handler' (as is MS's own KB article).  The other two lines don't actually seem to be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

It should be ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0 - you're missing 'Handler' (as is MS's own KB article).  The other two lines don't actually seem to be necessary.